# Principal component analysis - calculating variance

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Quoting Rahul's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component?lq=1):

> It's not hard to show that if the covariance matrix of the original
>   data points $x_i$ was $\Sigma$, the variance of the new data points is
>   just $u^{T}\Sigma u$.

The covariance between sets $X$ and $Y$ is defined as $\sum_i = \frac{1}{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$, where $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ denote the mean.

In some other material I've found it says something else than what I've quoted:
Here, the variance is not equal to $u^{T}\Sigma u$. It would be if $A$ in this case were multiplied by $\frac{1}{n}$. They say $A$ would be a covariance matrix if the coefficient was present. But it's not. It looks 'a bit' incompatible with the statement in the quote.

The question is - who is wrong here and what is variance equal to? I suppose Rahul is right saying that the variance is equal to $u^{T}\Sigma u$, where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix. But the picture below proves a different equality, so what's going on here?

[Here](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/PrincipalComponentAnalysis.pdf) on page 8, the author derives the equality supporting Rahul's claim (I can't quite understand what's going on there). Which one is correct?

[image]
[Source](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/09wi/Lects/lect14.pdf)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Similar : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174015/if-the-covariance-matrix-is-sigma-the-covariance-after-projecting-in-u-is?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb R^d$ be the set of sample points you are dealing with. Projecting onto a unit vector $v\in\mathbb R^d$ you get the samples $z_i := x_i^Tv\in\mathbb R$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. The sample mean of this list of numbers is
$$
\overline z = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i z_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i^T v = \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i^T\right) v = \overline x^Tv,
$$
where $\overline x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i$ is the sample mean of the unprojected data. Now the sample variance of the projected data is, by definition
\begin{align*}
\sigma_z^2 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(z_i-\overline z\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(x_i^Tv-\overline x^Tv\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(\left(x_i-\overline x\right)^Tv\right)^2.
\end{align*}

Note that what is called "$var(\mathbf v)$" in the slide you attached is *not* the sample variance $\sigma_z^2$, since the factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ is missing.

Hence, the two statements are not in conflict.

We can go on and obtain the result Rahul suggested:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_z^2
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(\left(x_i-\overline x\right)^Tv\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(x_i-\overline x\right)^Tv \left(x_i-\overline x\right)^Tv \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i v^T \left(x_i-\overline x\right) \left(x_i-\overline x\right)^Tv \\
&= v^T \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(x_i-\overline x\right) \left(x_i-\overline x\right)^T \right) v = v^T \Sigma_x v,
\end{align*}
where
$$\Sigma_x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(x_i-\overline x\right) \left(x_i-\overline x\right)^T$$
is the sample covariance matrix of the unprojected data.

Comment: Good, clarifying answer! The question is why the $\frac{1}{n}$ coefficient was omitted... Variance has a precise definition, so why they decided to ignore it?

Comment: @user4205580 To find the two eigenvectors $v_1$, $v_2$ the normalization is irrelevant. Maybe they didn't want to clutter up the slide. After all, they call their thing "variation" instead of "variance" ;-)