# Significance of eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the significance/geometric interpretation of eigen values or eigen vectors in a vector space?

Comment: We like to reduce transformations to combinations of simpler ones. A very simple kind of transformation is a dilation. We can often reduce a linear transformation to dilations to different extents along different directions. This is called diagonalization (strictly speaking, diagonalization over the real numbers). With a bit more work, we can also make eigenvalues tell us about rotation. What they cannot really tell us about is shear.

Comment: There is definitely an old question about this somewhere on the site with plenty of good answers.

Comment: [here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243533/how-to-intuitively-understand-eigenvalue-and-eigenvector)

Comment: actually I was [thinking of this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23312/what-is-the-importance-of-eigenvalues-eigenvectors)