# Can someone explain to me what eigenvalues and eigenvectors are and possibly provide a visual explanation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently struggling to get my head around what eigenvalues and eigenvectors truly are as Khan Academy says that eigenvalues are just a scalar by which a vector is scaled and the eigenvector is the resultant vector that is not equal to zero, but other sources say different things.

I was wondering whether someone would be able to provide a simple explanation of what eigenvalues and eigenvectors are, and it would be greatly appreciated if a visual supplement is provided. I need to learn these to find the general solution to a markov matrix and am becoming quite confused.

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Overview

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243533/how-to-intuitively-understand-eigenvalue-and-eigenvector?noredirect=1&lq=1