# Conceptual meaning of eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, condition-number

Can someone provide an intuitive/conceptual explanation for eigenvalues and eigenvectors? I know the mathematical definition $$Ax= \lambda x$$ which means that if x is an eigenvector, then it is only stretched or squeezed (i.e., does not change direction). I feel like I don't really understand why that is so important. I am in an optimization class, and eigenvalues/eigenvectors come up a lot. For example, in quadratic programming we have the form $$x^T H x + c^T x \text{ subject to }Ax\leq b$$ and if H is a positive semidefinite matrix (non-negative eigenvalues), this problem is convex and easier to solve than the non-convex case. Why? I think I also read once that if there are negative eigenvalues, the matrix is "ill-conditioned." Is this true? What does that mean?

Comment: I sympathize with your question.  I only truly learned the importance of eigenstuff after many years of study.  Think of it this way:  computing $Ax$ takes a lot of calculation.  Add up how many multiplications and additions it takes to calculuate $Ax$ when everything is $n$-dimensional.  Now do the same thing for computing $\lambda x$:  it only takes $n$ multiplications, that's it.  In some sense it is about efficiency.

Comment: In many applications, eigenvalues and eigenvectors reveal some physical quantities giving you a lot of information about the stability of a system, convergence of an algorithm, etc..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23312/what-is-the-importance-of-eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243533/305862