# covariance matrix eigenvalues eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a probabilistic or analytical meaning of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors
of covariance matrix of multivariate normal distribution?

Thank you

Comment: The accepted answer to the question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component may be of help here.