# Sample Variance in Principal Components Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, principal-component-analysis

I was reading this [Why is the eigenvector of a covariance matrix equal to a principal component?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component#). And in the top answer, the poster mentions that if the covariance matrix of the original data points $x_i$ was Σ, the variance of the new data points is just $u^TΣu$. I'm not sure why this is the case. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Suppose your data set consists of N vectors, each of length T. Let's denote them $\vec{x}_i$, (i=1, ..., N). The new data set consists of $\vec{y}_i$ (i=1, ..., N), $\vec{y}_i = \sum_{k=1}^N p_{ik} \vec{x}_k$.

Then the covariance matrix of the new data set has elements
\begin{eqnarray*}
C_{ij} &=& {1 \over T^{2/\alpha}} \vec{y}_i \cdot \vec{y}_j \\
&=& {1 \over T^{2/\alpha}} (\sum_{k=1}^N p_{ik} \vec{x}_k) \cdot (\sum_{l=1}^N p_{jl} \vec{x}_l) \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^N p_{ik} p_{jl} C'_{kl} \\
C &=& P C' P^T
\end{eqnarray*}
where P is the matrix with components $p_{ik}$ and C' is the covariance matrix of $\vec{x}_i$.