# Real and imaginary part of an Eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

Apology if my question not clear or appropriate. Consider a complex positive definite sample covariance  matrix (SCM) generated by a band limited signal on a set of sensors. Is there a relation between the real and imaginary part of the Eigenvectors of the SCM? Does the real and imaginary part signifies anything?

Comment: The real and imaginary parts will determine the direction of the eigenvector, which will be associated with the variance of the data. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but question was related to real and imaginary part individually. As I understand all Eigenvectors  are related to direction even if all it's components are real.