# (PCA) why the eigenvector points in the most “significant” direction of the data set

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

In Principal component analysis, why the symmetric covariance matrix's eigenvector points in the most “significant” direction of the data set?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Do you know what an eigenvector is? It's not just *any* eigenvector that gives the "**most** significant direction." It's an eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue. Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component?rq=1

Comment: @symplectomorphic : in your link they don't say that it is  because the $k$ first eigenvectors are the solution of $\min_P \|X -  X P P^T \|^2_F$ subject to $ P : n \times k \quad$ (with $ X : m \times n$ being the matrix of your $m$ points)