# Why are the eigenvalues of a covariance matrix equal to the variance of its eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning, covariance, variance

This assertion came up in a Deep Learning course I am taking. I understand intuitively that the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue will be the direction in which the most variance occurs. I understand why we use the covariance matrix's eigenvectors for Principal Component Analysis.

However, I do not get why the eigenvectors' variance are equal to their respective eigenvalues. I would prefer a formal proof, but an intuitive explanation may be acceptable.

(Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component))

Comment: As you build the matrix $M$ as a sum of outer products : $M = \sum{v}{v}^T$ what ends up in the respective elements are the expected values $M_{ij} = E[v_{i}v_{j}]$ with i and j being vector positions. This is all before any transformation to the space of principal vectors is done. Maybe it can help figuring out the rest.

Comment: As mentioned in Omnoms answer $M_{ij}$ will contain $\sum v_iv_j$ which is one way to estimate of $E[X_i X_j]$, assuming the components of vectors $v_i$ are samples drawn from the $X_i$ which are the random variables.

Comment: An eigenvector of a covariance matrix is not a random vector, so the variance of an eigenvector does not make sense. If it was a random vector, it would make more sense to talk about the covariance matrix of this random vector and not the variance.

Comment: Eigenvectors are unit vectors having variance … 1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a formal proof: suppose that $v$ denotes a length-$1$ eigenvector of the covariance matrix, which is defined by
$$
\Sigma = \Bbb E[XX^T]
$$
Where $X = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ is a column-vector of random variables with mean zero (which is to say that we've already absorbed the mean into the variable's definition).  So, we have $\Sigma v = \lambda v$ (for some $\lambda \geq 0$), and $v^Tv = 1$.

Now, what do we really mean by "the variance of $v$"?  $v$ is not a random variable.  Really, what we mean is the variance of the associated component of $X$.  That is, we're asking about the variance of $v^TX$ (the dot product of $X$ with $v$).  Note that, since the $X_i$s have mean zero, so does $v^TX$.  We then find
$$
\Bbb E([v^TX]^2) = \Bbb E([v^TX][X^Tv]) = \Bbb E[v^T(XX^T)v] = 
v^T\Bbb E(XX^T) v \\
= v^T\Sigma v = v^T\lambda v = \lambda(v^Tv) = \lambda
$$
and this is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: This part is crucial: `what do we really mean by "the variance of "?  is not a random variable. Really, what we mean is the variance of the associated component of `. Thanks!